# Exclude page numbering from certain pages

Tags: page-numbering

I'm working on my thesis and I need help with page numbering:
I'd like to exclude page numbering in some pages within my report (to be specific, in chapters titles pages). I've used this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty
     \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil}
     \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
```

However, even though the numbering did disappear in those pages, it kept taking those pages into consideration. Example: my report (the main text) doesn't start with page 1 but 3 (as it is preceded by 2 chapters titles pages).
I'm bad at explaining stuff, I hope you understood my problem, and I hope you can help.

Comment: Rather than mucking with the definition of `ps@plain`, why don't you just invoke `\thispagestyle{empty}` on those pages that are not to have a page number?  If you need to adjust the page number to suit, one can `\setcounter{page}{<number>}` as needed.

Comment: I tried it first, it didn't work. No idea why? I'm a newbie.